# Promise - Getting read as promise in one place and as 'undefined' in another

Tags: angular, promise, angular-promise

I'm creating a new Promise (only method in a class returning a promise) as

```
return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) { 
    ... mongo DB call
    if ( err ) {reject(err)}
    if ( data ) {resolve(data)}
})
```

When I return this, in one place I'm able to read this as a promise and get data using

```
promise.then(..)
```

But, when I try doing the same thing in another class (it is in the first line in both the classes), I'm getting an error that reads,

```
[TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined]
```

Has anyone faced a similar issue?

EDIT: As suggested, this is the actual code -

```
module.exports = {
  populateDashboard: function ( req, callback ) {

    var userInfo = {userName: 'Business User1', role: 'business'};
    console.log ('userInfo - ', userInfo); // Getting this value, obviously!
    var promise1 = roleAccessRepository.getUserRoleAccess (userInfo.role);
    promise1.then (
        function(data) {

        }
    ).catch(
        function(err) {
            console.log('error', err); // Error getting caught here
        }
    )}
}



module.exports = {
    fetchCampaignInfo: this.fetchCampaignInfo,
}
    fetchCampaignInfo = function ( role, userName, sectionName, callback ) {

      var campaignList = [];
      var promiseArray = [];

      var promise1 = roleAccessRepository.getUserRoleAccess (role);
      promise1.then (
        onRoleSuccess = function ( data ) {
            // This goes through fine
        }
    ).catch(
        function(err) {
            console.log('error', err); 
        }
    )}
}

module.exports = {
  getUserRoleAccess: function ( role ) {
    return new Promise (
      function ( resolve, reject ) {
        var roleAccess = mongoose.model ('roleAccess', userAccessRole);
        roleAccess.find ({role: role}, function ( err, data ) {
          if ( err ) {
            console.log ('getUserRoleAccess - error', err);
            reject (err);
          }
          console.log ('getUserRoleAccess - Data', JSON.stringify(data));
          resolve (data);
        });

      });
  }
}
```

Comment: There is clearly something wrong with YOUR code.  Promises don't do what you described.  So, the ONLY way we can help you is for you to show us the code that has the problem.  It is likely an issue with how you are using the returned promise.  And, please show us real code, not redacted or pseudo code (like you have in your answer now).  The issue is a detail in your actual code so the only way we can help you precisely is to see the relevant portion of your actual code.

Comment: Since you may be a bit new here, this site is about solving problems in actual code.  We do a really lousy job at theoretical questions that don't show the code in question.  That requires lots of questions and guesses on our part which is both super inefficient and often just an ineffective way to try to find an answer.  But, if you show us your actual code, we can usually provide a fairly quick and very specific answer that fixes the problem exactly.

Comment: Like you said, I'm a novice in both Angular and StackOverflow. And I also felt that it might be a common problem that someone can easily relate to. I've updated the code above anyways.

Comment: Always post the relevant code here when you first write the question.  Can you please be more specific about exactly where in your code you have a problem?  FYI, after calling `reject(err)`, you should `return` from the callback or use an `else` on your `if` so that the other code that follows does not run.  That isn't the cause of your issue, but it sure could confuse you.

Comment: This line is invalid code: `fetchCampaignInfo = function (role, userName, sectionName, callback) {` where it sites inside an object definition.  Did you mess up something in the copy to the question?  Or is this an actual syntax error in your code?

Comment: Also, why is `onRoleSuccess = ` present in this `promise1.then(onRoleSuccess = function(data) {`?  That's an odd way to do things.  Perhaps not an error, but odd.

Comment: Like I said, I'm a novice. Hence, I'm trying to get things to work first. Corrected the module.exports line and added return to reject (like you said, totally agree with that part). What do you mean by odd in the above comment? I just like giving names to the resolve - equivalent method in such cases for aiding readability.

Comment: You didn't respond to the most important question I had.  Where exactly in this code you've posted do you get the error `[TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined]`?

Comment: Updated in the code -  In the first block - `{console.log('error', err); // Error getting caught here}`

Comment: That `console.log()` just means that `roleAccessRepository.getUserRoleAccess(...)` is rejecting its returned promise.  You need to figure out why it is rejecting.  What line of code causes the `[TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined]` to be displayed.  That's what I thought you were asking about.

Comment: The strange part is that I'm able to log the data I got from the Mongo call before calling the resolve callback. Hence, I am not sure why it is rejecting.

Comment: It could also hit the `.catch()` if the code inside the `promise1.then()` handler right before it threw an exception.  You don't show any of that code so I have no idea whether that is happening, but that's another way to hit that `.catch()`.

Comment: Thanks sir! That helped. This was something that flew over my head. I didn't know that some exception inside the `then` would get caught here.

Answer (score 0):

I'll make this into an answer since it apparently led to you figuring out the problem:

It could also hit the `.catch()` if the code inside the `promise1.then()` handler right before it threw an exception. You don't show any of that code so I have no idea whether that is happening, but that's another way to hit that `.catch()`.

All `.then()` handlers are what is called "throw-safe".  That means if any code in a `.then()` handler throws an exception, it is automatically caught by the promise's `.then()` handling code and the promise is then rejected with the exception as the reason for the rejection.  So, any chained handlers after that `.then()` handler that threw the exception will see a rejected promise.  That means that the promise that is returned from `promise1.then()` becomes rejected so `promise1.then().catch()` will hit the `.catch()` handler.

Here's a simple example to illustrate:

```js
function delay(t) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        setTimeout(resolve, t);
    });
}

delay(100).then(function() {
    console.log("#1");
    throw new Error("some error");
}).then(function() {
    console.log("#2");
}).catch(function(err) {
    console.log("#3 ", err.message);
});
```

This will show the output:

```
#1
#3  some error
```

Comment: @RamanaSarva - Since it appears you may be new here, I'd like to explain that if your question is now answered, then you can indicate that to the community by clicking the green checkmark to the left of the best answer and that will also earn you some reputation points here for following the proper procedure.